# completar código para enseñar geometría

Tags: php

Tengo un código donde un visitante elige ciertas opciones relacionadas con geometría (número de lados y ángulos) No sé como hacer para que el código muestre un resultado dependiendo de las combinaciones que haga el visitante.

Agradezco cualquier colaboración.
Muchas gracias.
Adjunto aquí el código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Curso de geometría</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Geometría básica </h1>

<form action="calcular.php" method="post">

Polígono según número de lados: 
<BR>    
<select name="select1">
<option selected value="0">--- Selecciona una opción --- </option>
<option value="1" name="1"> Triángulo </option>
<option value="2" name="2"> Cuadrilátero </option>
</select>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>    
Relación entre ángulos:
<BR>    
<select name="select2">
<option selected value="3">--- Selecciona una opción --- </option>
<option value="4" name="4"> todos iguales </option>
<option value="5" name="5"> todos distintos </option>
</select>
<BR> 
<BR>
<BR>
Tipo de ángulos:
<BR>    
<select name="select3">
<option selected value="6">--- Selecciona una opción --- </option>
<option value="7" name="7"> algún ángulo recto </option>
<option value="8" name="8"> ningún ángulo recto </option>
</select>
<BR> 
<BR>
<BR>  
<input value="Calcular" type="submit"/>
<!--    Si es triángulo con todos los ángulos iguales y algún ángulo recto, no existe
    <!--    Si es triángulo con todos los ángulos iguales y algún ángulo recto, no existe
    Si es triángulo con todos los ángulos distintos y algún ángulo recto, es triángulo rectángulo escaleno.
    Si es triángulo con todos los ángulos distintos y ningún ángulo rescto, es triángulo obtusángulo escaleno.
    Si es cuadrilátero con todos los ángulos iguales y algún ángulo recto, es cuadrado.
    Si es cuadrilátero con todos los ángulos iguales y ningún ángulo recto, es un rombo.
    Si es cuadrilátero con todos los ángulos distintos y algún ángulo recto, es trapezoide.
    Si es cuadrilátero con todos los ángulos distintos y ningún ángulo recto, es trapecio.-->    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo que se hace con las selecciones ocurre en el archivo `calcular.php`. Edita tu pregunta para que agregues el contenido de ese archivo.

Comment: Esto parece que se podría solucionar sin necesidad de formularios con un simple script de JavaScript. ¿Por qué usar PHP?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro debe ser que así se lo pidieron en la clase.

Comment: con GWT se hace en 5 mins, y sin PHP

Answer (score 1):

Quizas la mejor opción seria con JavaScript, y asi según vas seleccionando algún select se van modificando los demás, de forma que si eliges triangulo en el primer select y en el segundo eliges "todos los angulos iguales" la opción 3 no te deje hacer nada. Si lo que quieres es que prueben las combinaciones y vean lo que es erróneo o es corercto, también lo podrias hacer con JavaScript, pero como quieres con php vamos a ello. Es un poco laborioso porque tienes que ir comprobando todas las combinaciones para dar los mensajes correspondientes, te voy a poner el ejemplo de como ir haciéndolo, no lo desarrollo entero, verás que es muy sencillo, tienes que ir rellenando las opciones del switch

```
<?
$html="<html><body>";
#sacamos los datos del formulario
$poligono = $_POST["select1"];
$relación = $_POST["select2"];
$tipo = $_POST["select3"];

switch ($poligono) {
   case 1:  #es triangulo
        switch ($relación){
           case 4: #lados iguales
                switch ( $tipo ){
                     case 7: # algún angulo recto
                           $html.="El triangulo con lados iguales y un angulo recto no existe";
                           break;
                     case 8:
                           $html.="El triangulo ...........";
                           break;
                }
                break;
           case 5: #lados distintos
                 switch ( $tipo ){
                     case 7: # algún angulo recto
                           $html.="El triangulo con lados distintos y angulo recto es triangulo rectángulo escaleno";
                           break;
                     case 8:
                           break;
                }
                break;

        }
        break;
   case 2: # es un cuadrado
       switch ($relación) {
       #repite el anidamiento y cambia los textos

       }
       break;            
}

$html.="</body></html>";
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba. Decidí hacerlo en PHP porque me permite mayor interacción con el usuario si decido subirlo a una página web con notificaciones por mail. Saludos.